# Why does kafkaTemplate send methods not work with a nullable key?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kafka

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html#sendDefault(K,V)

Calling above method from kotlin with a nullable key results in compiler warnings. Shouldn't the key be nullable? It is legitimate to want to produce a message occasionally with no key.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many overloaded methods you can use [one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html#send(String,V)) that accepts only `topic` and `value` if you don't want to pass the key

```
public ListenableFuture<SendResult<K,​V>> send​(java.lang.String topic, @Nullable V data)
```

As per the syntax from [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html#send(java.lang.String,K,V)), only `value` can be null since it is annotated with `@Nullable`

```
public ListenableFuture<SendResult<K,​V>> send​(String topic, K key, @Nullable V data)
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, I don't see any problems with adding `@Nullable` to the key parameter.

Comment: yeah, you guys already provided overloaded methods with variable args and i feel those are right ones to use as per requirement @GaryRussell

Comment: Right now If I want to send a nullable key i need to write `key?.let { kafkaTemplate.sendDefault(it, value) }?: kafkaTemplate.sendDefault(value)`. If we add the annotation it becomes `kafkaTemplate.sendDefault(key, value)`

Comment: i will suggest to use another overloaded method if `key` is null there is no point of sending null key  @JacobBotuck